# Can a graph model loaded with tensorflow.js use data on GPU without transferring it to the CPU first?

Tags: javascript, gpu, cpu, tensor, tensorflow.js

I am currently using tfjs 3.8 to load a segmentation model (loaded as a `tf.GraphModel`) on the client side. To create the input `Tensor`, I call `browser.fromPixels(imageData)`, which creates the `Tensor` on CPU from the `ImageData` object that is also on CPU. Since I'm using tfjs' `webgl` backend, the data is sent to the GPU when calling the `model.predict(tensor)` function. All of this works well, excepted that my `ImageData` object is created from an image on a canvas with a `WebGLRenderingContext`, meaning it comes from the GPU. This GPU->CPU->GPU data transfer is slowing down my process, which I am trying to optimize.

I briefly searched tfjs and could not find a way to create a `Tensor` on GPU to prevent the GPU->CPU data transfer. Is there a way I could keep my data on the GPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simply to provide the canvas with the webgl context to the `browser.fromPixels(canvas)` call. This will create the Tensor directly on the GPU.

Answer (score 1):

Detailed conversation on this topic is in a thread https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/5765